# Binomial optimization

Tags: probability, optimization, binomial-coefficients

Let suppose a fixed $0\leq p\leq 1$. The parameter $r$ changes from 0 to 1. Consider the following equation. My goal is to maximize $s_r$ over $r$. I did not find any closed form for $s_r$. Is there any way to solve this kind of optimization problem?
\begin{equation}
\frac{\gamma_{r}}{r}{{K-1}\choose{s_r}} \left(rp\right)^{s_r}\left(1-rp\right)^{K-s_r}+ \sum_{s = s_r+ 1}^{K-1} \frac{1}{r}{{K-1}\choose{s}}\left(rp\right)^{s}\left(1-rp\right)^{K-s} = 1-p.
\end{equation}
where $0\leq\gamma_{r}\leq1$.